# Flash message not visible in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.7, laravel-session

flash messages not visible in the view section, after adding these lines in the Kernel.php.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,      //Line no 1 added
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,    //Line no 2 added
];
```

Here is my working code, which is correct before adding these lines.

Controller Code:

```
return redirect('/admin/categories')->with('success','Record Successfully Added.');
```

View Code:

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
{{ $message }}
```

These lines are also necessary for me, I can't remove it. Can anybody have the solution, please let me know. **Thanks for advance**!

Comment: Where in the `Kernel.php` did you add those two lines?

Comment: the `ShareErrorsFromSession` should have no influence to your problem, but the `StartSession` might have, can you confirm that it works without StartSession?

Comment: If you added the `StartSession` somewhere in the kernel without removing it from where it was then you might be starting two different sessions

Comment: Alternatively, you can try get the session from controller,compact the variable name and pass it to blade @if($variable) ?

Comment: please post your `kernel.php` file in your question

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I'hv updated my question.

Comment: @matiit yeah, it's working fine when removing these two lines in karnel.php

Comment: @LimKeanPhang compact is another way to do this, but I want in the same manner.

Comment: @apokryfos how we start two different sessions in the kernal??

Comment: You shouldn't start two sessions.

Comment: @apokryfos can you please describe it a little bit more... b'coz I can't understand it.